# Looking for intentionally buggy code snippets

Tags: c++, lint

Hey, I'm looking for some database of intentionally buggy code in C++.
I want to give a presentation about static code analysis tools, and I want to show some examples in action.

Comment: I'll post you some of my code ;)

Comment: Try `site:thedailywtf.com +"C++" CodeSOD`.

Answer (score 5):

Gimpel Software shows every month bugs that were found using [PC Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) static code analyzer. You could test your tool on [those samples](http://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs.htm).